# Reading a cubin structure from a pointer

Tags: c++, cuda, structure

I am trying to read the contents a c++ structure(in windows) which has the following format

```
typedef struct __cudaFatCudaBinaryRec {
    unsigned long            magic;
    unsigned long            version;
    unsigned long            gpuInfoVersion;
    char*                   key;
    char*                   ident;
    char*                   usageMode;
    __cudaFatPtxEntry             *ptx;
    __cudaFatCubinEntry           *cubin;
    __cudaFatDebugEntry           *debug;
    void*                  debugInfo;
    unsigned int                   flags;
    __cudaFatSymbol               *exported;
    __cudaFatSymbol               *imported;
    struct __cudaFatCudaBinaryRec *dependends;
    unsigned int                   characteristic;
    __cudaFatElfEntry             *elf;
} __cudaFatCudaBinary;
```

I have a pointer to this structure (void *ptr)

Now I am looking to read the contents of this structure.

```
__cudaFatCudaBinary *ptr2=(cudaFatCudaBinary*)ptr;
cout<<ptr->magic;//This works fine
cout<<ptr->key;//This crashes my program..bad pointer results..why?
```

The above is consistent with all non pointer and pointer members. What am I doing wrong?

**ADDED:**

ok let me elaborate on the problem. Yes, the address pointed to by "key" is NULL and so it is for all the pointer members. But I know for sure the structure has valid data. It is used by a driver function to generate a handle and it executes fine. All I need is to copy the entire image of the structure and store it in a text file. How would I do it? Why are some of the member fields null? I am thinking of a brute force way to find the address limits of the structure. But the values themselves seem to be invalid when read and I don't know how to go about it!

**ADDED 2**

[Memory Dump](http://codepad.org/3PMxBeS1) of the structure

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of the `key` field? Right now, you're sending a `char*` to `cout`, and if it's an invalid pointer (say, the null pointer), your program crashes. Perhaps you should cast the pointer to a number (`unsigned long`? my C is rusty...) first.

Comment: You need to show us the contents of the object which `ptr` points to. Most probably `key` is not initialized to anything and hence the UB.

Comment: printf("The pointer value is %p\n", ptr->key);

Comment: @tinctorius Thank you for your reply. Please take a look at my addendum

Comment: @ash - in which case my answer about printing `char*` pointers as `void*` instead is exactly what you want then to avoid it trying to just output a string.

Comment: @awoodland Ya agreed if I just want to look at the address. But I tried probing into the memory and the pointer has null value. My question is about the step before this one. How do I get the values of the structure properly?

Comment: Are you sure your (void*) is a (cudeFatCudaBinary*), and not, say, (cudaFatCudaBinary**)?

Comment: @tinctorius Good observation ! I suspected the same and verified it some time back..Nope..It is a * !

Comment: Can you dump that piece of memory to a file and post it somewhere? Offset `ptr`, size `sizeof(__cudaFatCudaBinary)`?

Comment: @Tinctorius The memory dump is here [code pad](http://codepad.org/3PMxBeS1). I am not sure what you mean by offset ptr and size ?( of what)?

Comment: It's all good :) It seems that, as of CUDA 4.0, `gpuInfoVersion` is the only interesting field in this struct (as mentioned in [this thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=200857)).

Comment: True. But it so happens that I need the pointer to the structure to emulate an API call

Comment: @Tinctorius actually your link helped me..Apparently nvidia has changed the structure for cuda 4.0 and I had to use that to get the image! Thanks for the link!! If you can post this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Done, so that people may notice it when looking for an answer to the same problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of CUDA 4.0, the format of this struct drastically changed. The value of `magic` is now different and `gpuInfoVersion` is now a pointer to a struct that contains the actual data. For more information, you might want to read [this thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=200857).

Answer (score 1):

`cout << ptr->key` will print as a 0-terminated string whatever key points to, *not* the pointer itself. If key is `NULL` or otherwise invalid then this will be undefined behaviour. (In this case a "crash")

If you just want to print the pointer itself make sure you print it as a `void*` pointer:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr->key);
```

Comment: @Als I thought I covered that with "or otherwise invalid"

Comment: Its all guess work, unless OP posts the relevant code, So nevermind.

Comment: @Als Thank you for your reply. Please take a look at my addendum